# Geometry of Young's experiment for optical path length

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, geometry

I am currently studying the textbook *Modern Optical Engineering*, fourth edition, by Warren Smith. When presenting the concept of optical path length, the author says the following:

> With reference to Fig. 1.13, it can be seen that, to a first approximation, the path difference between $AP$ and $BP$, which we shall represent by $\Delta$, is given by
>
> $$\Delta = \dfrac{AB \cdot OP}{D}$$
>
> [image]

I'm having difficulty understanding how the mathematics $\Delta = \dfrac{AB \cdot OP}{D}$ corresponds to the figure. I suspect that there is some use of trigonometry and/or geometry that I am not seeing. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the following diagram:

[image]

When the distance $L$ between the slit plane and the screen is large compared to the distance $d$ between the slits, we can assume $S_1P$ and $S_2P$ are parallel to each other. And the $\delta$ in the image represents the optical path difference.

Now consider the light orange coloured triangle. Here $\sin \theta=\delta/d$. As $L>>d$, we can assume $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ and hence $\theta\approx\delta/d$.

Now consider the light blue coloured triangle ($POQ$). Here $\tan\theta=y/L$. Using small angle approximation we can tell $\theta\approx y/L$.

So equating $\theta\approx\delta/d$ and $\theta\approx y/L$, we get $\delta/d\approx y/L$.

If you haven't figured it till now, I have just derived the expression in your question but used different symbols in accordance with the diagram in my answer.

---

<sup>Image taken from the question - *[In Young's double slit experiment, why are the two theta values equivalent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362983/238167)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In reality, the distance $L$ is not necessarily large compared to the distance $d$ between slits, right? So what happens then? Or is this one of those cases in geometric optics where we assume the "paraxial approximation" (since you used approximations in your answer, I think this might be the case)?

Comment: @ThePointer: If the condition $L>>d$ is not satisfied then the equation in your question becomes invalid as it's based on small angle approximation. "_Paraxial approximation_" is something to do with non-marginal rays in case of lenses and mirrors in geometric optics and I don't think we call this kind of approximation by that term. Further, double-slit experiment is a consequence of wave nature of light rather than its corpuscular behaviour.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I meant the "small angle approximation". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that AB is very small compared with D.  Then the two triangles are similar and the sine of the small angle is OP/D = Δ/AB